# Spring Security error on try redirect "Access is Denied"

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Realized the implementation of spring security in my project, but I'm having trouble defining a redirect. When access is locked I need to redirect that user to a specific URL.

When i put the tag "access-denied-handler" i hope he redirect to the page defined on the bean, but don't happen.

security-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<!-- Method Security -->
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler" />
</security:global-method-security>


<bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator"/>
</bean>

<bean id="permissionEvaluator" class="net.pontoall.hemisphere.security.HemispherePermissionEvaluator"/>

<!-- Publicos -->
<security:http pattern="/layouts/**" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/messages/**" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/test/**" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/login/**" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/install/**" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/cobredireto/**" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/hotsite/**" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/captcha.jpg" security="none" />

<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

    <security:access-denied-handler ref="HemisphereAccessDeniedHandler"/>

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

    <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/home" 
                         authentication-failure-url="/login?logout=true" 
                         authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
                         authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"/>

    <security:logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" invalidate-session="true" success-handler-ref="logoutHandler"/>
</security:http>

<!-- Authentication Manager -->
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <!-- Custom Authentication provider -->
    <security:authentication-provider ref="hemisphereAuthenticationProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="hemisphereAuthenticationProvider" class="net.pontoall.hemisphere.security.HemisphereAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="net.pontoall.hemisphere.security.HemisphereAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/home" />
    <property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="no" />
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="net.pontoall.hemisphere.security.HemisphereAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login" />
</bean>

<bean id="logoutHandler" class="net.pontoall.hemisphere.security.HemisphereLogoutHandler"/>

<bean id="HemisphereAccessDeniedHandler" class="net.pontoall.hemisphere.security.HemisphereAccessDeniedHandler">
    <property name="errorPage" value="/error/permissao"/>
</bean>
```

Bean Java - HemisphereAccessDeniedHandler.java:

```
public class HemisphereAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {

private String errorPage;

public String getErrorPage() {
    return errorPage;
}

public void setErrorPage(String errorPage) {

    if (errorPage == "") {
        errorPage = "/";
    }

    this.errorPage = errorPage;
}

@Override
public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {
    // Set the 403 status code.
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
    response.sendRedirect(errorPage);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered what was happening. I have a Spring MVC @ExceptionHandler and he is capturing the error.

```
@ExceptionHandler
public ResponseEntity<String> handle(Exception exception, HttpServletRequest requestMain) {
    String erro = exception.getMessage();
    PusherRequest request = new PusherRequest("hemisphere-web", requestMain.getSession().getId());
    request.triggerPush(erro);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    return new ResponseEntity<String>(exception.getMessage(), headers, HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
}
```

Comment: Good, consider using the _error-page_ attribute of _access-denied-handler_ if you just need a simple redirect anyway, e.g. `<access-denied-handler error-page="/access-denied.html" />. (http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-access-denied-handler)

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I had done that in the first test, but it had not worked then I went the other way :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Redirect has its own HTTP status code (3xx), see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html. The method `response.sendRedirect` should automatically set the HTTP status code to 307 (Temporary Redirect, see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect).

But you're setting the HTTP status code to Forbidden (403) prior to redirect.

Therefore try removing the `response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN)`. You could also post  a `curl` dump to see the raw server output.

Comment: I tried but didn't work, I'm debugging it not entering in the class.